# Google Compute Engine Image to create a VM in a On Prem environment

Tags: google-compute-engine

We are in a situation in which we need replicate the Google CE environment we have set up to be replicated in a an OnPrem VM.

Can we download and use a Google Compute Engine image to create a VM in a On Prem environment? If yes, could you please point me to right links?

Regards,
Nikhil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. Here are instructions for exporting an image from GCE:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#export_an_image_to_google_cloud_storage

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a good opportunity to look at using a [configuration management tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software). Doing this would allow deployment and management of your infrastructure across a variety of platforms (cloud, on-prem, etc).